# ng-model gets undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird situation where i am trying to grab a value from the input field but when i try to get it, shows undefined.

So, here is the input field that i set the ng-model

```
<input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Location" 
                    name="loc"
                    ng-minlength="6"
                    ng-model="service.orgname"
                    class="form-control"
                    required>
<button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="submit(service)" ng-disabled="serviceForm.$invalids">
```

Now, in my controller, i set the orgname to some value

```
.controller('editHistoryCtrl',function($scope,$state,$http,$localStorage,$sessionStorage){
    $scope.service = {};
    $scope.service.orgname = "hello";

    $scope.submit = function(service){
          console.log($scope.service.orgname);

    };
})
```

It shows the value in input field as hello,but it says undefined in the log, where it should print "Hello".
Is there anything wrong with my work?

Comment: So where is your custom submit ?

Comment: i updated , please see . Thank You @AhmetCanGüven

Answer (score 0):

change  `ng-disabled="serviceForm.$invalids"`  to `ng-disabled="serviceForm.$invalid"`

Comment: Hello guys i figured out the problem. it is due to the minlength

Answer (score 0):

Guys i think i found the problem. It shows undefined due to the ng-minlength. Since "Hello" is 5 char , it is the problem as ng-minlength=6.

Comment: finally i found out , hahaha.